# Execute openssl using bash for loop

Tags: bash

I have a list of IPs I need to check if they support TLS1.2, and I am using Openssl for that. However I can't seem to automate the process within the Bash script. It only executes on first IP and waits for my input. I read I have to either add `< /dev/null` or `echo "x"` but it does not help.  I tried:

```
for i in `cat scope`; do openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect $i:443 < /dev/null; done
```

or:

```
for i in `cat scope`; do echo "x" | openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect $i:443 < /dev/null; done
```

EDIT: solved, port 443 was not open on 2nd IP, that's why it was waiting.

Comment: Can you try running that manually for one IP and paste the terminal input/output?

Comment: @anishsane if I run on 1 IP, without for loop it gives me me output and finishes normally and I get my prompt back: `openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect $(head -1 scope):443 < /dev/null`. However if I run that using for loop it just stops after 1 IP is checked.

Comment: ok, is there any error on second line? maybe trailing spaces or any special character, etc? Also, does it run manually for 2nd line (`openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect $(sed -n 2p scope):443 < /dev/null`)?  Or perhaps the second IP does not respond and thus, the process just hangs? In that case (hang case), try adding something like `timeout 10` before `openssl`.

Comment: could you post the content of `scope`? I couldn't reproduce the problem with a random example...

Comment: Ok, apparently port 443 was filtered on 2nd IP.. I completely forgot to check that and assumed it's open on all of them. Well sorry, was my fault. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to use `nmap` instead of `s_client` to check the TLS handshake (and it will catch the case when port are not open).

```
for i in `cat scope`; do 
  if nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 "$i" | grep "TLSv1.2" >/dev/null; then 
    echo "$i supports TLSv1.2"
  else
    echo "$i doesn't support TLSv1.2"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Indeed, that's better :)